# logCat errors - Unclear Exceptions

Tags: android-emulator, android-logcat

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError[FATAL ERROR] - This is the error that I keep receiving from logCat. I do believe I have the appropriate permissions declared in the manifest.xml because I have cross-checked with the manifest file provided in the tutorial. There are no errors in the code as I have followed the tutorial rather carefully.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error which you are getting comes during execution if some **static block** is having any problem.
 i.e. Not able to initialize a variable in static block or null pointer somewhere.

Any issue with the static block and you will get this exception.
Please **check once your static block and the code inside,** cleaning it will take care of the issue.

If problem persists. Please paste here the static block and logcat too.

Comment: Hello.  First of all, thanks. Actually the problem was far different from what I thought. The application had not been built properly with gradle since I always selected 'open project' instead of 'import project.' this stops the application from building with gradle.